# I can not connect my tablet with my PC through ftp or http from file manager

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, file-transfer

I have android kitkat on my asus tablet and when I open the asus file manager and try to make PC transfer the app give me a url to use in the browser like this: http://192.168.0.11:4433 but I get timeout error also when I try other file manager apps that give me ftp access through windows explorer I get same problem !!

I have windows 10 64bit pro updated to latest version

what I should do to fix this problem ?

Comment: do you have your tablet  connected to the same network?

Comment: @MarkYisri yes same wifi network and my PC connected though wifi too